# How can I use GCS Delete in Data Fusion Studio?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-data-fusion

Apologies if this is very simple but I am a complete beginner at GCP.

I've created a pipline that picks up multiple CSVs from a bucket, wrangles them then writes them into BigQuery. I want it to then delete the contents of the bucket folder the files came from. So let's say I pulled the CSVs using `gs://bucket/Data/Country/*.CSV` can I use GCS Delete to get rid of all the CSVs in there?

As a desperate attempt :D, in the Objects to delete, I specified `gs://bucket/Data/Country/*.*` but this didn't do a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Google Cloud Storage Delete plugin documentation](https://github.com/data-integrations/google-cloud/blob/release/0.13/docs/GCSBucketDelete-action.md#properties) its necessary to put each object separating it by comma.

There are [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/170687196) asking for the possibility to allow suffixes and prefixes when using this plugin, you can use the **+1** button and provide your feedback about how this feature could be useful.

On the other hand, I thought in a workaround that could be work for you. Using the [GCS documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects#storage-list-objects-python) I have created an script to list all *csv* objects in a bucket, you  only have to copy & paste the output in the **Objects to Delete** property of the plugin. Its important to mentioned that I used this workaround with 100 files more-less, I'm not sure if it's feasible to use  with a larger amount of files.

```py
from google.cloud import storage
bucket_name="MY_BUCKET"
file_format="csv"

def list_csv(bucket_name):
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name)
    for blob in blobs:
        if file_format in blob.name:
            print("gs://"+ bucket_name + "/" + blob.name+",")
    return None

list_csv(bucket_name)
```

Comment: I see, thanks for the feedback Enrique. The code works though I was hoping GCS Delete would work so that I could simply schedule the pipeline and leave it to do it's thing. Let's hope the feature is added. Cheers!